# Не работает код. Выдает ошибку скана

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package born.to.learn;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tasks {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Чтобы найти периметр круга задайте радиус: ");
        float r = scan.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Периметр круга = " + 2 * Math.PI * r);
    }
}
```

Comment: А без дробной части ввести если - работает? А если через запятую дробную часть ввести, а не через точку?

Comment: странно почему через запятую работает, а через точку нет

Comment: в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Потому что в локальных настройках операционной системы разделителем дробной части указана запятая. Как это всё именно в Java устроено я не знаю, но суть обычно в этом.

Comment: просто когда записываешь переменные флоата то нужна точка, а не запятая. странная java)

Comment: спасибо тебе за помощь!

Comment: А это потому, что код программы от локали не зависит, он должен быть универсальным. А вот исполнение кода - зависит от локали )

Answer (score 3):

Как написали в комментариях, разделитель в числах с плавающей точкой задаётся системой. Но код должен быть универсален и не зависеть от настроек системы.

Поэтому, вот решение:

https://www.cyberforum.ru/java/thread1002604.html

Если коротко, то можно установить локаль для сканера.

```
scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Или делать замену символов считав строку, а не число, и уже после парсить строку в число.

```
 .replace(",",".")
```

Comment: Даже если по ссылке можно найти решение, лучше приведите решение (хотя бы основную часть) прямо в ответе. Ссылки имеют свойство портиться со временем и ваш ответ может потерять актуальность, если вся информация в нём будет только по ссылке.

Comment: @CrazyElf согласен, спасибо за замечание, исправил.